# PyTorch MNIST shape issue

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist, pytorch-dataloader

I've tried to run this code (from an example online) but am unsure what the error is and how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions or need more information more than happy to help.

Code:

```py
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.utils.data import SubsetRandomSampler, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
import torch

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.29730626, 0.29918741, 0.27534935),
                                                     (0.32780124, 0.32292358, 0.32056796)),
                                ])

mnist_train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='data/pytorch/MNIST', train=True, download=True,
                                     transform=transform)
mnist_valid_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='data/pytorch/MNIST', train=True, download=True,
                                     transform=transforms)
mnist_test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='data/pytorch/MNIST', train=False, transform=transform)

next(iter(mnist_train_dataset))
```

Error:

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\GitProjects\PyTorchTests\1mnist\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    next(iter(mnist_train_dataset))
  File "C:\Users\[Username]\.conda\envs\pytorch1\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py", line 145, in __getitem__
    img = self.transform(img)
  File "C:\Users\[Username]\.conda\envs\pytorch1\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 95, in __call__
    img = t(img)
  File "C:\Users\[Username]\.conda\envs\pytorch1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[Username]\.conda\envs\pytorch1\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 270, in forward
    return F.normalize(tensor, self.mean, self.std, self.inplace)
  File "C:\Users\[Username]\.conda\envs\pytorch1\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py", line 363, in normalize
    tensor.sub_(mean).div_(std)
RuntimeError: output with shape [1, 28, 28] doesn't match the broadcast shape [3, 28, 28]
(pytorch1)
```

Comment: MNIST has grayscale images so only single-channel (1x28x28) but you are trying to normalize with 3-channel mean and std deviation in your `transform`. [See this line](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/648c0bd2f1f12a8767b4a737d6e8577a8192c42d/mnist/main.py#L114) where they use a single scalar mean and std deviation value.

Answer (score 0):

Plz change to this

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize((0.29730626,),
                                                 (0.32780124,)),
                            ])
```